# react-native source_files path of podspec file is affect to auto linking?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, podspec

eg.

1. I have 'react-native-awesome' module, and ios file path is below

```
   ios/RNAwesome/RNAwesome.h
   ios/RNAwesome/RNAwesome.m
   ios/RNAwesome.xcodeproj
```

2. I wrote podspec like below

```
require 'json'
package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'package.json')))

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  ...some specification

  s.source_files = "ios/*.{h,m}" //correct path is "ios/**/*.{h,m}"


  ...
end
```

It occur error when I use auto linking? (at RN > 0.60.x)